# Get distinct value from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My xml is like this

```
    <syddata lastUpdated="19.04.2013 12:40 ">
  <data itemnumber="ln1044-wh-36" variant1="White" variant2="Size 36" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="wh" var2code="36" estocklevel="0,000000000000" sortering="0"></data>
  <data itemnumber="ln1044-wh-38" variant1="White" variant2="Size 38" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="wh" var2code="38" estocklevel="0,000000000000" sortering="0"></data>
  <data itemnumber="ln1044-wh-40" variant1="White" variant2="Size 40" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="wh" var2code="40" estocklevel="0,000000000000" sortering="0"></data>
  <data itemnumber="ln1044-wh-42" variant1="White" variant2="Size 42" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="wh" var2code="42" estocklevel="0,000000000000" sortering="0"></data>
  <data itemnumber="ln1044-wh-44" variant1="White" variant2="Size 44" variant1group="Farver" variant2group="Størrelser" var1code="wh" var2code="44" estocklevel="0,000000000000" sortering="0"></data>
</syddata>
```

and I have a for each loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="$variants/syddata/data">
     <xsl:value-of select="@variant1"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which will output white as 5 times. But I just want to out put it one time. Means I want to get distinct values. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just the first `data` element with each `@variant1` attribute value by making sure sure there are no preceding sibling elements with a matching attribute:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$variants/syddata/data">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::data[@variant1 = current()/@variant1])">
     <xsl:value-of select="@variant1"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <xsl:variable name="variant1" select="@variant1"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::data[@variant1= $variant1])">
            <xsl:value-of select="@variant1"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get distinct values in XSLT 1.0, one of the most efficient ways is by using an `xsl:key`. ([Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).)

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="variant1" match="data" use="@variant1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/syddata">
        <distinct-values>
            <xsl:for-each select="data[count(.|key('variant1',@variant1)[1])=1]">
                <value><xsl:value-of select="@variant1"/></value>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </distinct-values>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working example: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqU

Answer (score 0):

When the below transformation runs on your Input XML will get the required output

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each-group select="syddata/data" group-by="@variant1">
<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(@variant1)"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: group by is an invalid attribute for XSL for each.thats the error i am getting now

Comment: @AKS: This is XSL version 2.0. Please check your version and apply it for `<xsl:for-each-group>`

Comment: can please you show me how i can apply this xsl version to for each loop only

Comment: @AKS: Do you need for XSL version 1.0 only. If possible change your xsl version to 2.0 and use the above coding